# Why is the font (for titles and parts )on my scrbook document showing up as if it is an article document?

Tags: fonts, formatting, scrbook

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMFmr.png)[image]

I am trying to format a document in `scrbook` and the titles of the parts, chapters, etc show up as if they were apart of an article document. How can I make them revert to the same font as regular `scrartcl` `scrbook titles.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{scrbook}


\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[sf]{titlesec} 

\definecolor{gray75}{gray}{0.65}
\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{0pt}}

\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\flushleft
\fontseries{b}\fontsize{80}{100}\selectfont}{\fontseries{b}\fontsize{100}{130}\selectfont \textcolor{gray75}\thechapter\hsp}{0pt}{\\ \Huge\bfseries}[]

\titleformat{\part}[hang]{\flushleft
\fontseries{b}\fontsize{80}{100}\selectfont}{\fontseries{b}\fontsize{100}{130}\selectfont \textcolor{gray75}\thechapter\hsp}{0pt}{\\ \Huge\bfseries}[]

\title{Math Handouts}

\author{XYZ}

\date{2021}

\let\cleardoublepage=\clearpage


\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\chapter{Preface}
something

\chapter{Introduction}
somebody

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\part{Algebra}
\chapter{Chapter name}

\part{Number Theory}
\chapter{Chapter name}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I would really appreciate help, this issue is quite urgent (summer project for class due tomorrow). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read the title.

Comment: Thank you for the welcome, how do you suggest I change this question so that It can be understood by someone who did not read the title?

Comment: By editing the body of your question. And what's the point of writing **strong text** in it?

Comment: I just edited the body of the post, there was no meaning to "strong text", I am not sure why it was in the body.

Comment: Change that font with, *e.g.*, `\setkomafont{disposition}{\sffamily}`.

Comment: As for why, we can’t tell without a MWE. Cou;d you edit your document down to the minimum that reproduces the bug, and post the source?

Comment: Sure, I just added a small part of the code with the major text sections removed. The main things wrong are the change of font, the centering, and trying to move the large numbers higher on the page as well as have the text next to the number rather than below.

Comment: What @Davislor meant was to further reduce your code as much as possible: Does it concern the title page at all? If not, no need for `\maketitle`, e.g. What's with the color definitions? Does it have to be the `lemma` environment? etc.

Comment: I deleted all of the useless code. It doesn't concern the title page, there are color definitions for the numbers regarding the chapters. No it does not relate to the lemma environment. It is relating to the chapter titles, part titles, section titles.

Comment: If I remember correctly, combining the titlesec package with a Koma script class is not recommend. Probably this is the reason for the issue you observe.

Answer (score 4):

Do not use package `titlesec` with one of the KOMA-Script classes.

You can use option `chapterprefix=true` to get a prefix line for chapters. You can change font elements `chapter`, `chapterprefix`, `part` and `partnumber`.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,
  %a4paper,% default
  open=any,% <- added
  chapterprefix,% <- added
  numbers=noendperiod
]{scrbook}

\usepackage{fix-cm}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{gray75}{gray}{0.65}

\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{\thechapter\autodot}
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\Huge}
\setkomafont{chapterprefix}{\fontsize{100}{130}\selectfont \color{gray75}}

\renewcommand*{\partformat}{\thepart\autodot}
\setkomafont{partnumber}{\fontsize{100}{130}\selectfont\color{gray75}}
\setkomafont{part}{\normalcolor\Huge}
\renewcommand*{\raggedpart}{\raggedright}

\title{Math Handouts}
\author{XYZ}
\date{2021}
%\let\cleardoublepage=\clearpage% replaced by option open=any
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\chapter{Preface}
something
\chapter{Introduction}
somebody
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\part{Algebra}
\chapter{Chapter name}
\part{Number Theory}
\chapter{Chapter name}
\end{document}
```

To adjust the vertical space before and after the headings and between the prefix line and the text, you can use options `beforeskip`, `afterskip` and `innerskip` in the optional argument of `\RedeclareSectionCommand[...]{chapter}` and `\RedeclareSectionCommand[...]{part}`.